# Integral of exponential $\int_0^{+\infty} \exp\left(-a^2 x\left(\frac{x-6}{x-2}\right)^2\right) \frac{dx}{\sqrt{x}}$

Tags: definite-integrals

Calculate the following integral

$$\int_0^{+\infty} \exp\left(-a^2 x\left(\dfrac{x-6}{x-2}\right)^2\right) \dfrac{dx}{\sqrt{x}}$$

I think the relation between this integral and function gamma is clear, But I do not know what variables change I do. Any Hint Pliss!

Comment: @ pablocn_ what about x=0 ?, it's seems not work in your domain

Comment: if its work in your domain it's seems to use inverse laplace transforma to error function

Comment: $I=\dfrac{\sqrt\pi}a.~$ An obvious first substitution is $t=\sqrt x~,$ since $\big(\sqrt x\big)'=\dfrac1{2\sqrt x}$

Comment: I was wondering if you considered applying residue calculus? http://mathfaculty.fullerton.edu/mathews/c2003/ResidueCalcMod.html

Comment: @Lucian, can you provide some further hints? The first substitution is obvious, however I can't solve it further by any real methods I tried. The value is very surprising, since it's equal to just $$2 \int_0^{\infty} e^{-a^2 u^2} du$$

Comment: @YuriyS That is a Gaussian integral which can be done by https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_integral

Answer (score 2):

Let $I$ be the integral in the question. First set $u^2=x$ so that:
\begin{align}
I=\int^\infty_0 \exp\left(-a^2x\left(1-\frac{4}{x-2} \right)^2\right)\,\frac{dx}{\sqrt[]{x}} =2\int^\infty_0 \exp\left(-a^2u^2\left(1-\frac{4}{u^2-2} \right)^2\right)\,du
\end{align}
Now notice that: $$I=\int^\infty_{-\infty} \exp\left(-a^2\left(u-\frac{4u}{u^2-2} \right)^2\right)\,du=\int^\infty_{-\infty} \exp\left(-a^2\left(u-\frac{2}{u+\sqrt[]{2}}-\frac{2}{u-\sqrt[]{2}} \right)^2\right)\,du$$
By [Glasser's Master Theorem](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/GlassersMasterTheorem.html) we get the result, namely:
$$I=\int^\infty_{-\infty} \exp(-a^2u^2)\,du=\frac{\sqrt[]{\pi}}{|a|}$$
*And we finally see the result Lucian suggested to be true three years ago.*